# static class on .web project silverlight

Tags: wcf, silverlight, class, sockets, static

I have been having a problem for a long time , but so far have not got a solution and I hope you can help me .

I have a Silverlight application where I use WCF for queries to retrieve information from the database and also for the communication between client ( Duplex ) and Socket (receive and send information between my application and others).

To control Duplex , when the client accesses a specific module of my application , I link that customer to a static class that I have on my Projeto.Web ( Application start ) , as in the code below :

```
    //static Class
    public static class ncClientes
    {
            private static List<IncServicoDuplex> clientesSupRecAlarme = new List<IncServicoDuplex>();
            public static List<IncServicoDuplex> ClientesSupRecAlarme
            {
                    get { return ncClientes.clientesSupRecAlarme; }
                    set { ncClientes.clientesSupRecAlarme = value; }
            }
    }

    //Método chamado pelo WCF quando o cliente acessa o módulo
    public void VinculaCliente(string strProjeto)
    {
            //GetCallbackChannel - obter o canal de comunicação entre o serviço e o cliente - retornará a instância do canal entre o serviço e o cliente.
            IncServicoDuplex cliente = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IncServicoDuplex>();

            //A palavra-chave lock marca um bloqueio de instruções como uma seção crítica, obter o bloqueio de exclusão de mútua para um determinado objeto, 
            //executar uma instrução e, em seguida, liberar o bloqueio.
            switch (strProjeto)
            {
                    case "ncPrincipal|Alarme":
                    case "ncAlarme":
                    case "ncConfiguracao|Supervisao":
                            lock (ncClientes.ClientesSupRecAlarme)
                            {
                                    ncClientes.ClientesSupRecAlarme.Add(cliente);
                            }
                    break;
            }
    }
```

When I make a change to the database , all of my online customers who are at the receiving module that change the WCF service , use the following code :

```
    //Método no meu WCF que transmite a informação de alteração, inclusão ou exclusão de um cliente para os outros
    public void SupervisaoAlarmeOnline(ncAlarme objAlarme)
    {
            var varClientesAlarme = new List<IncServicoDuplex>(ncClientes.ClientesSupRecAlarme);

            foreach (var item in varClientesAlarme)
            {
                    try
                    {
                        item.SupervisaoAlarmeOnlineRetorno(objAlarme);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ncClientes.ClientesSupRecAlarme.Remove(item);
                    }
            }
    }
```

My problem happens when I get some information by Socket ( class located in projeto.Web ) that creates an instance of my ServicoWCF and call the method to send the received information to clients. Apparently, my static variable is being reset when called on this side of the application.

Is there any difference on " which side " I call the service ? When I call it on WCF client side my static variable gets the correct count , but when I call it on the Socket class , count is set to 0.

I hope you can help me , I tried to be as clear as possible , if there is any doubt please let me know.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Somebody can help me? :(

Comment: I`m not sure if its just a typo, but it seems to me you are adding to the ncClientes.ClientesSupRecAlarme and retrieving from ncClientes.clientesSupRecAlarme . Note the difference between "C" and "c". Also, the "set" property is not activated by adding a new element to the collection, it is activated when you give a new value to the collection, for example another collection.

Comment: I discovered the error..but I dont know how to solve. I used a method that save a txt file at my C:/Temp/ to now where is my service. I use this code to take the local of my svc that I'm using.

When I'm running using VS2010 I received this situation:

GetSite("");//C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Serv\sys\bin

RecebeMsgSocket();//C:\Proj\Proj_13\MyProjSlt.Web\bin

When I'm running public all (application and service) in IIS:

GetSite("");//C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Serv\sys\bin

RecebeMsgSocket();//C:\inetpub\wwwroot\App\bin

How can I publish that I will use for all situation my svc that are on system folder?